# how to select one row's position in a list-view not by ItemIdAtPosition?

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view and I edit its items via contextual menu, I need to get the row id of an item then pass it to another activity via bundle then in second activity the data will be shown from database and from there they can be edited.

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            data_ID = adapterView.getItemIdAtPosition(i);
            actionMode = Block_A_Info.this.startActionMode(new android.view.ActionMode.Callback() {
                @Override
                public boolean onCreateActionMode(android.view.ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
                    actionMode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu,menu);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onPrepareActionMode(android.view.ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
                    actionMode.setTitle("Edit");
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onActionItemClicked(android.view.ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
                    Intent open = new Intent(Block_A_Info.this,Edit_A_Info.class);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putLong("ID_INFO",data_ID);
                    open.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(open);
                    return false;
                }
```

but in that case there is an id positioned 0!! and another problem will arise when i delete one row then it will select wrong position for an item.

here is the code written in another activity to set the data in textvies:

```
    Bundle int_id = getIntent().getExtras();
    set_id = int_id.getLong("ID_INFO");
    Cursor info_rec = myDb.RecoveryInfo(set_id.toString());

    if(info_rec.getCount() == 0){
        Toast.makeText(Edit_A_Info.this,"Error!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    while (info_rec.moveToNext()) {
        et_num.setText(info_rec.getString(1));
        et_name.setText(info_rec.getString(2));
        et_person.setText(info_rec.getString(3));
        et_phone.setText(info_rec.getString(4));
        et_data.setText(info_rec.getString(5));
    }
```

how can I select the desire item in a list-view?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should move `data_ID = adapterView.getItemIdAtPosition(i);` into the `onActionItemClicked` method

Comment: You should use the variable `long l`  that represents the id of the view clicked.
`final data_ID = l ;`

Comment: Thanks but it does not work. I already define a long variable for data_ID